# What is the image name of the chevron for UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator?

Tags: ios, image

I would like to use the stock chevron in a different part of my app. Does anyone know the name of the image so I can just call [UIImage imageNamed:@"AccessoryDisclosureIndicator.png"] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can access the image directly but if you intend to use it for a button, you can get it with the `UIButton`'s `buttonType` – `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure`.

```
UIButton * disclosureButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get that. Custom image would be the way to go.

Comment: Correct - you can **not** get the arrow, sadly.  (So silly of Apple!)  Full discussion ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836606/use-table-view-disclosure-indicator-style-for-uibutton-ios

Answer (score 0):

If you need customize the color. You can use this instead of including new images:
https://github.com/bitmapdata/MSCellAccessory