# iOS 8 Auto Layout with UITableViewCell and UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8, ios-autolayout

My project is having an iOS8 compatibility issues in a custom `UITableViewCell`. I am getting the following error

```
Assertion failure in -[EditableTextCell _setHostsLayoutEngine:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3318.16.25/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:2760
2015-02-10 23:23:16.959 App_name[2883:507063] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Must translate autoresizing mask
into constraints to have _setHostsLayoutEngine:YES.'
```

I have seen similar questions such as  [UITableViewCell throwing exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854095/uitableviewcell-throwing-exception) and other questions like [UITableview Cell exception - 'Must translate autoresizing mask into constraints to have _setHostsLayoutEngine:YES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709190/uitableview-cell-exception-must-translate-autoresizing-mask-into-constraints) but none have been helpful. I have removed the constraints and I still get the error.

I am using auto layout. **EditableTextCell** mentioned in the error above is a custom `UITableViewCell` with `UITextFieldDelegate` and I am using it in many xib files. My view hierarchy is as follows:-

1. View_Portrait

   - Portrait_TopContentView

     - Editable Text Cell -- this is the custom class EditableTextCell

       - Content View
     - Table View Cell

       - Content View
     - Button
   - Portrait_TableContainerView
   - portrait _Tab Bar

     - UITabBarItem1
     - UITabBarItem2
2. Similar structure for the landscape view.

I would really appreciate any help. Please let me know if I can provide more information.

**UPDATE:** I have tried some solutions but this is still not working for me. Before I `setFrame:` for the **EditableTextCell** I put the following lines of code:

```
    [self.pSearchEditCell setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
    [self.pSearchEditCell.textField setFrame:textFieldFrame]; 
    [self.pSearchEditCell.textField layoutIfNeeded];
```

where `pSearchEditCell` is the custom  table cell of `UITableViewCell`and has the `UITextField`. But this approach is not working for me.

Comment: Have you used this line translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO for every UIElement added programmatically in your code. if you haven't try this once.

Comment: No I haven't used this line. I will try it out today and let you know if this worked for me.

Comment: Hi @Karish any solution for this? I keep getting this error but unable to find a good solution for this

Comment: Hi @HongZhou, there is no elegant solution to it. The custom table cell has to be part of the story board.

Answer (score 1):

Had this same issue. Eventually I just used the cell in a `UitableView` it seems iOS8 doesn't like it too much if you use cells outside of `UITableView`.

Comment: what were the constraints that you set where the constraints the same for the cell and the table. I am not sure how to do it, can you give me more information. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're trying to ask. The constraints for the cell get set in the custom cell class. and the uitableview has its own constraints

Comment: Not nesting the table cell in my storyboard was my problem when getting this error.