# How to fix "Must translate autoresizing mask into constraints to have _setHostsLayoutEngine:YES."?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I'm making a custom cell on UITableView using storyboard and I assign each element to class.But when I run the project it says:

> Must translate autoresizing mask into constraints to have _setHostsLayoutEngine:YES.

here is my code:

```
var image : UIImage = UIImage(named: foodImages[indexPath.row])!

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("timelineCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    let object = dataArray[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView).image = image
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel).text = object["firstName"] as? String
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(4) as! UIImageView).image = UIImage(named: "des5.jpg")


    return cell
```

I got the error on :
`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("timelineCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell`

How can I fix that?

Comment: Below link might be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217195/why-do-i-get-must-translate-autoresizing-mask-into-constraints-to-have-sethost